# Trouble logging in with Flask-Security: 'User' has no attribute 'get_user'

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-security

When I use Flask-Security's login form, I get the following error. It's telling me that I don't have a `get_user` method, (which is a part of my `user_datastore`).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_security/decorators.py", line 225, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_security/views.py", line 75, in login
    if form.validate_on_submit():
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_wtf/form.py", line 101, in validate_on_submit
    return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_security/forms.py", line 230, in validate
    self.user = _datastore.get_user(self.email.data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'get_user'
```

When I dug into Flask-Security's `datasource.py`, I see the following method:

```
def get_user(self, id_or_email):
    """Returns a user matching the specified ID or email address."""
    raise NotImplementedError
```

This seems like an abstract method and must be implemented within my `User` model. If that's true, why do none of the [Flask-Security examples](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html#id1) implement this method? If I try to add the method to my `User` model, things don't get much better. Here's my model with the experimental overridden method:

```
from extensions import db
from blog.models import Post
from sentence.models import Sentence
from roster.models import Roster
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
from flask_security import UserMixin, RoleMixin

# Helper table for a many-to-many relationship
roles_users = db.Table('roles_users',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
        db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    # general variables
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(155))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(155))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=True)
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())

    # app-specific variables
    paid_until = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    lifetime = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    # relations
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
    sentences = db.relationship('Sentence', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.password = kwargs['password']
        self.email = kwargs['email']
        if kwargs.get('first_name', False):
            self.first_name = kwargs['first_name']
            self.last_name = kwargs['last_name']

        # create a roster
        roster = Roster("default", self.email)
        db.session.add(roster)
        db.session.commit()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

    # __str__ is required by Flask-Admin (not using?), so we can have human-readable values for the Role when editing a User.
    # If we were using Python 2.7, this would be __unicode__ instead.
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # __hash__ is required to avoid the exception TypeError: unhashable type: 'Role' when saving a User
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)

    def get_user(self, *args):
        # I had to use *args or I'd always get missing 1 required positional argument
        for arg in args:
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=arg).first()
            if user:
                return user
'''    
    def find_user(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Returns a user matching the provided parameters."""
        raise NotImplementedError

    def find_role(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Returns a role matching the provided name."""
        raise NotImplementedError
'''
```

The above approach results either in `missing 1 required positional argument` if I don't use `*args`. As the model is written above, the app doesn't crash but says "Specified user does not exist", which is not the case as I can see the user in the database CLI. So, *do I need to implement the `get_user` method*?

Comment: When modify the `get_user` method to simply `return db.session.query(User).filter_by(email="known@email.com).first()` I get instead that my password is wrong (it's not). So if my model and my template check out, there must be something with how I control Flask-Security's views.

Comment: Ah ha! The `get_user` method is overridden by `SQLAlchemyUserDatastore`, not by the `User` class. So why then do I get `AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'get_user'` when I try to login? Why is the controller trying to call `get_user` on a `User` object and not on my `user_datastore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in Flask app's `__init__`. As suspected, Flask-Security's attempt to call `get_user` using the User model indicated the wrong object was passed when calling `security.init_app(app, user_datastore)`. The same parameters from the instantiation of the `user_datastore` were being reused for `security.init_app()` which is why the User model was being mistakenly accessed.